# why is this function analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic on an open set $D$ with isolated singularity at $w$.
Suppose that $|f(z)|$ approaches infinity as $z$ approaches $w$.

Show that $1/f(z)$ is analytic.
In the solution it uses definition of the limit to get :
there exists $d>0$ such that $|f(z)|>1$ whenever
$0<|z-w|<d$

Hence $1/f(z)$ is well defined and analytic on $B(w,d)\setminus\{w\}$ and $w$ is an isolated singularity.

I do not get the entire last line!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 1/f(z) is bounded in that deleted neighborhood, can u show w is removable for 1/f(z)?

Comment: So because it's bounded it is analytic?

Comment: If bounded in a deleted nbhd, by Riemann's Principle ($\omega$ is removable for $f(z)$ if $\lim_{z \to \omega} (z-\omega) f(z) =0$), u will see $\omega$ is removable. That is all u need to care.

Answer (score 1):

So, we know that $|f(z)|$ goes to infinity at $w$, so by the definition of a limit, we can find for every $N>0$ a $d>0$ such that when $|z-w|<d$ then $|f(z)|>N$. In the above we choose $N=1$ and so we find a $d$ such that $|f(z)|>1$ in a disk $D$ of radius $d$ around $w$. Which means $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is well defined on $D$ (since $f(z)$ is not zero there).

Comment: Makes sense, but why is 1/f(z) analytic?

Comment: There is a standard result that says you can invert a power series with nonzero constant coefficient. This power series will have nonzero radius of convergence, so you can choose a neighborhood of $w$ such that $1/f(z) $ is analytic.

Answer (score 0):

$1/f(z)$ is differentiable anywhere in $B(w,d)\setminus\{w\}$ because of the chain rule (whose proof from real analysis carries over to the complex case) -- it is the composition of $f$ and $1/z$, both of which are known to be differentiable.

Being differentiable in the open set $B(w,d)\setminus\{w\}$ means that the function is analytic there.